# redis timeseries data and timezones

Tags: php, redis, key-value, nosql

I'm trying to implement a timeseries db to store simple counters using redis (and php, but the language shouldn't be relevant i think). So I've implemented my redis keys as follows (simplified):

someprefix:YYYY-MM-DD:somecounter

Now when i want to get a range of data for a specific interval i just get all keys for the specific range and that's all working fine. (YYYY-MM-DD is the date as UTC)

Now i want to implement the ability to get data according to some timezone X.
My question is: is there any way this key schema can be used for that with any degree of accuracy?

I'm guessing not, since there's no time information at all so i'll also have to add at least the hours and minutes to the key so timezone conversion works correctly. I also probably should save the information in smaller time intervals otherwise when converting timezones there are cases where I would end up getting all data for a different day when the timezone difference shouldn't be more than 13h therefore giving me wrong results, am I right?

Would it be more appropriate to just use unix timestamps instead of the formatted date on the redis keys? For example, if I later on decide to store data with smaller precision, say per hour or per each 10 minutes, what would be a more flexible key format?

Hope I was able to explain my issue correctly, but please feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to go with epoch (UNIX timestamp) when you have to deal with timezone.

I would suggest bucking timestamps to frame the Keys. For example an event happened at timestamp 1409800502515(Thu, 04 Sep 2014 03:15:02 GMT), you could bucket it at Hour level or Day level like this

```
Hour bucket = 1409800502515 - (1409800502515 % (60 * 60)) = 1409800500000
Day bucket  = 1409800502515 - (1409800502515 % (24 * 60 * 60)) = 1409800464000
```

and frame keys like

```
someprefix:1409800500000:somecounter OR
someprefix:1409800464000:somecounter
```

For example for calculating the page views per hour, find the appropriate hourly bucket and increment the counter

```
mypage.html:1409800464000:page_views INCR 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, but as an example, consider the following scenario:
A client that's on a different timezone (say UTC +1), does a request for data from 2014-09-02 to 2014-09-06.
My system will convert the dates the client has supplied to UTC, so after the conversion i have 2014-09-01 23:00:00 to 2014-09-05 23:00:00 and i'll end up getting all data for day 1 when in reality i would only need 1 hour from that day.
So my question is: is creating a time bucket per day really useful in this case? And even if I only bucket per hour, there are timezones with 15 and 30m offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure how you're doing "get all keys for the specific range and that's all working fine" but if you're using KEYS someprefix:* note that this is not a recommended practice for production. Consider using the SCAN command that's available from v2.8 instead.

Secondly, you could consider using an ordered set for counting. So, following your convention, you'll have a key called `someprefix:somecounter` that you'll be ZADDing to members with the epoch as their score. Use the epoch and the counter's reading as a unique member name (e.g. '1409800500000:1` where 1409800500000 is the epoch and 1 is the counter's value).

Note that you can measure time resolutions from years to microseconds - it all depends on how much div you apply to the original epoch before setting the score.

Comment: Hello Itamar. Right now, I'm saving different days on different keys as I stated on the initial post. And no, not using the keys command. I'm simply looping through all the keys in the requested interval, so if a client requests data from 2014-09-01 to 2014-09-05, i just use a loop in code to get all keys for those dates and create an array that looks something like "day => counter" that in turn is used to populate a graph. The important issue is how to store the dates in redis so I can quickly perform timezone conversion on it and return the relevant range in the client's tz.